# a question about Nminimize

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have 10 equations and 10 unknown parameters such as alpha1,alpha2,a1,a3,... which I want to find them by minimizing

```
eq = -2 A3 + (-30 A1 + A3)^2 - 2 c2 alpha[3] + 4 c4a alpha[3]^3 + 
 8 e3 alpha[1] beta[1] + (4 e3 alpha[1] alpha[3] + 
   2 d2 beta[1])^2 + (4 e3 alpha[1]^2 + 2 d2 beta[3])^2 + (-3.14231 - 
   2 c2 + 2 d2 + 12 c4a alpha[1]^2 - 4 e3 beta[3])^2 + (-1.49499 - 
   2 c2 + 2 d2 + 4 c4a alpha[1]^2 + 4 e3 beta[3])^2 + (-2.1067 - 
   4 c2 d2 + 24 c4a d2 alpha[1]^2 - 16 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 - 
   8 d2 e3 beta[3])^2 + (-0.0277073 - 4 c2 d2 + 8 c4a d2 alpha[1]^2 - 
   16 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 + 8 d2 e3 beta[3])^2 + (-2 A1 - 2 c2 alpha[1] + 
   4 c4a alpha[1]^3 + 
   e3 (4 alpha[3] beta[1] + 4 alpha[1] beta[3]))^2 + (alpha[
    1] - (0.092631 alpha[1])/(beta[1] Sqrt[
       1 - (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3])))/Sqrt[
        64 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 + 
         4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3]))^2]] + 
      alpha[1] Sqrt[
       1 + (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3])))/Sqrt[
        64 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 + 
         4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3]))^2]]))^2
```

I  solved this equation with Nsolve and I have the exact answers,but I coudn't solve this equation by Nminimization command.I think one of equations is  complicated

```
((alpha[1] - (0.092631 alpha[1])/(beta[1] Sqrt[
      1 - (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3])))/Sqrt[
       64 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 + 
        4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3]))^2]] + 
     alpha[1] Sqrt[
      1 + (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3])))/Sqrt[
       64 e3^2 alpha[3]^2 + 
        4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha[1]^2 + e3 beta[3]))^2]]))^2)
```

the Nminimization can't give us a good answer. How can I solve these equations by the Nminimization command?

Comment: Welcome! I have formatted the question for you. In future posts, please use the formatting tools available to you.

Comment: you have really not shown enough detail to give any useful advice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is probably unbounded if your vars are left free. You could get something out of it under reasonable assumptions, though:

```
vars = Variables@eq;
const = And @@ Thread[Variables@eq > 1];
NMinimize[{eq, const}, vars]
(*
{-1593.64, {A1 -> 110.452, A3 -> 3314.57, c2 -> 1., c4a -> 3.36665, 
  d2 -> 1., e3 -> 1.1436, alpha[1] -> 1., alpha[3] -> 1.66815, 
  beta[1] -> 23.6565, beta[3] -> 3.04301}}
*)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have been added some assumptions

Comment: alpha[1] > 0, alpha[3] >0, A1>0, A3>0. They are my assumptions. With these assumptions, I have get the residual of order 10^(-7). I want to have a solution with the residual of order 10^(-20) or less than it. Do you know how we can simplify the complicated equation? Is there any other method to solve such system of equation?